# How to read a specific portion of a txt file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, for-loop, readlines

**I need to extract a portion of text from a txt file.** 
 The file looks like this:

STARTINGWORKIN DD / MM / YYYY HH: MM: SS 
... text lines ... 
... more text lines ... 
STARTINGWORKING DD / MM / YYYY HH: MM: SS 
... text lines I want ... 
... more text lines that I want ...

- *The file starts with STARTINGWORK and ends in text lines.*
  **I need to extract the final text portion after the last STARTINGWORK, without the STARTINGWORK str**

I tried use 3 for loops (one to start, another read the between line, and the last to end)

```py
     file = "records.txt"
     if file.endswith (".txt"):
       if os.path.exists (file):
         lines = [line.rstrip ('\ n') for line in open (file)]
         for line in lines:
             #extract the portion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a variable that saves all the lines you have read since the last `STARTINGWORK`.
When you finish processing the file you have just what you need.

Certainly you do not need to read all the lines to a list first. You can read it directly in the open file and that returns one line at a time.
i.e.:

```py
result = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("STARTINGWORK"):
            result = []       # Delete what would have accumulated
        result.append(line)  # Add the last line read
print("".join(result))
```

In the `result` you have everything after the last STARTINGWORK, inclusive you can keep the `result [1:]` if you want to delete the initial `STARTINGWORK`

**- Then in the code:**

```py
#list
result = []

#function
def appendlines(line, result, word):
  if linea.startswith(word):
    del result[:]
  result.append(line)
  return line, result

with open(file, "r") as lines: 
  for line in lines:              
    appendlines(line, result, "STARTINGWORK")
new_result = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in result[1:]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
file = "records.txt"
extracted_text = ""
    if file.endswith (".txt"):
        if os.path.exists (file):
            lines = open(file).read().split("STARTINGWORKING")
            extracted_text = lines[-1] #Here it is
```

Comment: this will not work with more than 2 STARTWORKING. In the text can actually have 2 of it, but can increasy randomly. So the objective is reach the last lines after the last STARTINGWORK

Comment: @BenjamínSerra Why won't this work now? Did you actually try it?

Comment: @BenjamínSerra the line: `open(file).read().split('STARTINGWORK')` will make a list of all the text sections in-between every occurrence of "STARTINGWORK". Then you can simply take the last element in that list, and the rest of Akaisteph7's code is just to properly remove the date and time.

Comment: @BenjamínSerra Please mark the correct answer if your question was resolved.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Yes I'm trying with this code. But is still not working, I'm getting the whole text or the numbers 22 51 if I use extracted_text. I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/

Comment: @BenjamínSerra Are you sure you are doing exactly what is here? Did you remove `lines = [line.rstrip ('\ n') for line in open (file)]` and `for line in lines:` from your code?

Comment: Oh I can't put the code here, but I did exactly as you said. Removing `[line.rstrip ('\ n') for line in open (file)]` and `for line in lines:` from the code. Is giving me back this numbers 22 51, from the last line 08/06/2019 15:58:40

Answer (score 2):

You can use `file_read_backwards` module to read file from end to beginning. It helps you save time if the file size is big:

```
from file_read_backwards import FileReadBackwards

with FileReadBackwards("records.txt") as file:
    portion = list()
    for line in file:
         if not line.startswith('STARTINGWORKING'):
            portion.append(line)
         else:
            break
portion.reverse()
```

`portion` contains lines desired.

Comment: When I try this it give me back except OSError. I'm using try and except for validate the path of the file.

Comment: I changed the file name to `records.txt`.

Comment: If I print portion, I'm getting the full text :/

Comment: It works fine for me. maybe there is a character before `STARTING WORKING`. You can make small dummy text file and try the code on it and debug it.

Comment: It work, was misspelled ('STARTINGWORKING') on the txt file. The only left is that I need to strip \n on the portion, but it's not big deal! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would take the `regex` path to tackle this:

```
>>> import re
>>> input_data = open('path/file').read()
>>> result = re.search(r'.*STARTINGWORKING\s*(.*)$', input_data, re.DOTALL)
>>> print(result.group(1))
#'DD / MM / YYYY HH: MM: SS\n... text lines I want ...\n... more text lines that I want ...'
```

Comment: print(result.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: This work better and simple than other answer. Thank you!

Comment: @GUNTERSAMA Glad you found a solution but I don't think this is simpler..

Answer (score 1):

The `get_final_lines` generator tries to avoid `malloc`ing
more storage than necessary,
while reading a potentially large file.

```
def get_final_lines(fin):
    buf = []
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('STARTINGWORK'):
            buf = []
        else:
            buf.append(line)

    yield from buf


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('some_file.txt') as fin:
        for line in get_final_lines(fin):
            print(line.rstrip())
```